# Tag Form fecha sozinha

Tags: php, html, html-tags

Quando envio esse código html via ajax ele exibe corretamente, porém fecha a tag Form logo após a abertura da mesma, existe outra forma de fazer isso? ou há algum erro de sintaxe.

```
$FormUserCad = '<div class="Ctn_Form_Cad">
        <div class="input_form_cad">
            <div>
                <div><form action="oi.php" method="post"></div>
                <div><label>Nome:<label></div>
                <div><input name="nome" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><label>Idade:<label></div>
                <div><input type="text"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="input_form_cad">
            <div>
                <div><label>Rua:<label></div>
                <div><input type="text"></div>
            </div>...
</form> <--



$retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => $FormUserCad);
            echo json_encode($retorno);
            exit();
```

Comment: Mas se você abre um `form`, ele tem que ser fechado mesmo pela lógica, senão seu formulário não funcionará. Não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: ele fecha sozinho, exemplo <form action="oi"></form> não ao final do código como desejado, e ele retira o </form> do final do código

Comment: Todo elemento HTML que é aberto será fechado pelo navegador, independente se você fechou corretamente ou não, o navegador constrói um término a partir do último elemento fechado corretamente. E sim, é um erro de sintaxe deixar seu html com a tag aberta. Inclusive ele também toma a liberdade de mover seu elemento de lugar, como por exemplo, se você colocar um script src, abaixo do navegador, fora do body, ele irá corrigir, colocando-o dentro do body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajuste seu html para a forma correta da estrutura html. E depois tente usar o [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
$FormUserCad = '<div class="Ctn_Form_Cad">
       <form action="oi.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <div><label>Nome:<label></div>
            <div><input name="nome" type="text"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><label>Idade:<label></div>
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><label>Rua:<label></div>
            <div><input type="text"></div>
        </div>

        ...

       </form>
   </div>';

    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => htmlspecialchars($FormUserCad,ENT_QUOTES));
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
```